# vcrpy record cassettes doesn't record in a test using test_client.post

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I'm implementing pytest and I want to record the answer of a request using vcrpy.

I'm using flask 1.0.2, pytest 4.5.0, pytest-flask 0.15.0 and vcrpy 2.0.1. I implemented a restful api using flask. I wrote a test but I would like to record the response of the request and vcr is not recording the response.

My endpoint is:

```
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Blueprint

class CompanyResource(Resource):

    def post(self):
        response = jsonify({
            "timestamp": datetime.utcnow()
        })
        response.status_code = 201
        return response


api_bp = Blueprint('dashboard', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp)
api.add_resource(CompanyResource, 'company', endpoint='company')
```

The test is the following

```
import pytest
import vcr

from flask import url_for

base_vcr = vcr.VCR(
    cassette_library_dir='tests/dashboard/fixtures',
    record_mode='once'
)


def test_create_company(client, company_data, headers):
      with base_vcr.use_cassette('create_user.yaml'):
           response = client.post(url_for('dashboard.company'),
                                  json=company_data,
                                  headers=headers)
```

I expect a file auto-generated on the directory specified. But when I run the test the cassette was not generated. The thing is that if I change `client.post` by `requests.post` the response is recorded for a get request, but if I try with a post an error is yield:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/api/dashboard/company': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///api/dashboard/company?
```

Do you have any suggestions to test my post endpoint and record the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late but vcrpy has a list of libraries it records the HTTP requests for. `requests` is one of them, and the others are mentioned in https://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#compatibility.

- aiohttp
- boto
- boto3
- http.client
- httplib2
- requests (both 1.x and 2.x versions)
- tornado.httpclient
- urllib2
- urllib3

Not sure what test client fixture you are using in your pytest, but if you use `requests` to call your endpoint successfully, it should record the response for you.